# Type error while inverting a dictionary containing tuples

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, tuples, typeerror

```
operations_dict = {
    "identity": np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]),
    "sigma_1": np.array([[1, -1], [0, -1]]),
    "sigma_2": np.array([[-1, 0], [-1, 1]]),
    "sigma_3": np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]]),
    "C3": np.array([[-1, 1], [-1, 0]]),
    "C3-2": np.array([[0, -1], [1, -1]])}

tuple_dict = {k: tuple(v) for k, v in operations_dict.items()}
inv_tuple_dict = {v: k for k, v in tuple_dict.items()}
```

I am working on a dictionary containing containing arrays. Because arrays are not hashable, I converted them to tuples. However, when trying to invert this dictionary so that I can use the values as key to get the keys, I get an error.
Type error: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'. I checked the type of the entries in the tuple_dict, all were tuples and strings. Would anyone have a solution? Thank you.

Comment: You are creating a tuple of ndarray, the objects inside the tuple must be hashable for the tuple to be hashable

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can hash your ndarrays and use the result as keys in the inverted dict.

```
    tuple_dict = {k: hash(v.tobytes()) for k, v in operations_dict.items()}
```

You need to save the hash result to be able to access your inverted dict.

```
operations_dict = {
        "identity": np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]),
        "sigma_1": np.array([[1, -1], [0, -1]]),
        "sigma_2": np.array([[-1, 0], [-1, 1]]),
        "sigma_3": np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]]),
        "C3": np.array([[-1, 1], [-1, 0]]),
        "C3-2": np.array([[0, -1], [1, -1]])}

tuple_dict = {k: hash(v.tobytes()) for k, v in operations_dict.items()}
hashes = list(tuple_dict.values())
inv_tuple_dict = {v: k for k, v in tuple_dict.items()}
print(inv_tuple_dict[hashes[0]])
```